# Flutter - How to reuse component: make a stateless or just a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to know what is the best practice to reuse a component: Is it better to create a file with just a "widget method" or with a complete class with stateless/full widget?

For example, I would like to reuse the appbar, what is the best practice?

**mainAppbar.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ressources/customColors.dart';

AppBar mainAppbar() {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: Text(
      "Test",
      style: TextStyle(color: CustomColors.mainColor),
    ), 
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: CustomColors.mainColor),
        onPressed: () {},
        splashRadius: 20,
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.tune, color: CustomColors.mainColor),
        onPressed: () {},
        splashRadius: 20,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

OR

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ressources/customColors.dart';

class MainAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final AppBar appBar;

  const MainAppBar({Key? key, required this.appBar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        "Test",
        style: TextStyle(color: CustomColors.mainColor),
      ),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: CustomColors.mainColor),
          onPressed: () {},
          splashRadius: 20,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.tune, color: CustomColors.mainColor),
          onPressed: () {},
          splashRadius: 20,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(appBar.preferredSize.height);
}
```

In this example, I used the appbar, but it's the same question for all others components I would like to reuse :)

One more thing: i'm using GetX package!

Thank you!

Comment: According to me you should make a separate class for your appbar  so that you can use it on multiple pages . So I think file would be better

Comment: Hello! Just to be clear: each example is in external file (the first example is in mainAppbar.dart, same for the second). I just want to know if creating a class is necessary! :D Thank you!

Comment: Yeah I think its necessary beacause than only you would be able to create properties/instances that you will use in the required pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good resource on this question on *Flutter*'s youtube channel.

[Widgets vs helper methods | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo)

You can also check out other videos in the playlist from [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU1fRV40Ec8200rX6OuQkmnl)